# Javascript array of objects specific format

Tags: javascript, arrays, morris.js

I got an array of objects and I want to display it like:

```
data: [
    { year: '2008', value: 20 },
    { year: '2009', value: 10 },
    { year: '2010', value: 5 },
    { year: '2011', value: 5 },
    { year: '2012', value: 20 }
],
```

I need this to use it for [morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/), but I can't do it manually like object[0] because I dont know the total length of the array.

Is there any way to get these format from this one?

```
Array [ Object ]
```

Comment: [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: That's just JSON format (basically). You'll probably need to put the `data` pair inside a object literal for it to parse properly.

Comment: set your array as the data object

Comment: there is no such thing as JSON format. JSON format is literally javascript. That is why it's called JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: `Array [ Object ]` can be anything. that could already be the format you're asking for. learn to use the console to inspect your variables and your life will get much easier.

Comment: please add the data from `Array [ Object ]`.

Answer (score 0):

set your array as the data objct
i.e.
data:yourarray